# How to check state of a checkbox if it doesn't have "checked" attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, checkbox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check the state of a checkbox using Selenium Webdriver or Javascript but having done a lot of research I still can't do it.

**My problem is**: the checkbox doesn't have "checked" attrubute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="site[new_sign_up]" id="site_new_sign_up" value="1">
```

For regular normal checkboxes I use the next string to detect if a checkbox is checked or not:

```
if (checkbox.GetAttribute("checked") != null && checkbox.GetAttribute("checked").Equals("true"))
```

I know it could be done with JS:

```
$get("isAgeSelected").checked == true
```

But still I can't do it as my checkbox doesn't have "checked" property.

If using selenium I check "Selected" property of element it also doesn't tell me the truth of checkbox state.

**Any suggestions of how to do it?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: I think you just need to check `checkbox.GetAttribute("checked") != null` nothing else

Comment: just use `checkbox.checked` it's native JS and doesn't depend on the checked attribute

Comment: WebElement has a method isSelected() in java which returns true if a checkbox or radio is selected. Else false.

Answer (score 5):

The DOM API provides a checked property on all input types, regardless of if they have a checked attribute or not (or even if they aren't check-able, i.e. text elements)

You **SHOULD NOT** rely on a checked attribute being present to determine if the checkbox is checked.

```
var x = document.createElement('input');
console.log(x.checked); //false
x.type = 'checkbox';
console.log(x.checked); //false
x.checked = true;
console.log(x.checked); //true
console.log(x); //<input type="checkbox"> - see? no checked attribute, yet it is still checked
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This work well. Seems to be the best answer)

Comment: @Adman, don't you know how to deal with it if I do need to use IWebDriver element for this? So I don't know its CssSelector and that's why I can't use "getElementById"  method of JS.

Comment: @Adam, he is not relying on the `checked` attribute. The method `checkbox.GetAttribute("checked")` returns the `checked` property if it's present and the attribute if not.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you should use .prop instead of attribute

```
$('input').prop('checked') //true-false meaning the checkbox is checked or not
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve in js by using below code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#site_new_sign_up').click(function(){
    if($('#site_new_sign_up').prop('checked')) {
         console.log('Checked');
    } else {
        console.log('Not Checked');
    }
 })
});
</script>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="site[new_sign_up]" id="site_new_sign_up" value="1">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check and uncheck the checkbox by using this code.

> if(checkBox1.getAttribute("checked") != null) // if Checked
>
> checkBox1.click();  //to Uncheck it